# Syntax for return action is incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get a `List<Cities>` using autocomplete from a web service. The list is successfully returned to the function but the return assignment is not right

I am using console.log to see returned results and this is what I get:

**For `console.log(itemList)` I get:**

[Object, Object, Object]

```
0:Object
CityId: 7932
CityName: "BADGERYS CREEK"
__type: "Cities"
__proto__: Object

1: Object
CityId: 7933
CityName: "BALGOWLAH HEIGHTS"
__type: "Cities"
__proto__: Object

2: Object
CityId: 7934
CityName: "BALMAIN EAST"
__type: "Cities"
__proto__: Objectlength: 3

__proto__: Array[0]
....
```

To be able to read the reply from the web-service I have to loop the result. I need to do some thing like this but don't know what is the correct syntax:

```
$("#txtDeliveryCity").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "SfWebService.asmx/GetCitiesByPrefix",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{'prefixText' :" + "'" + request.term + "'}"

                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (itemList) {                           

                            var listCityName = [];
                            var listCityId = [];

                            var counter = 0;
                            for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {

                                listCityName[i] = itemList[i].CityName;
                                listCityId[i] = itemList[i].CityId;
                            }

                             // ------ This is not right:
                            return { label: listCityName, value: listCityId }; 


                        }));

                    }
                });
```

**Server side:**

```
public class Cities
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
{

[WebMethod]     
public List<Cities> GetCitiesByPrefix(string prefixText)
{
    var service = new Cities();
    var cities = service.GetCityByPrefix(prefixText);                

    return cities;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code if you are facing issues in rendering the text and value field.

```
$("#elementID")
          .bind("blur", function(event) {
              var currentText = $(this).html();
              if (currentText === undefined || currentText === "") {
                  this.innerHTML = this.value = "";
              }
          }).autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: function(request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "your url",
                      data: {},cache: false,type: "GET",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(datas) {response(datas.d);},
                      error: function(error) {alert(error.responseText);}
                  });
              },
              focus: function(event, ui) {
                  $(this).html(ui.item.CityName);
                  return false;
              },
              select: function(event, ui) {
                  $(this).html(ui.item.CityName);
                  $(this).attr("value", ui.item.CityId);
              }
          }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, value) {
              return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", value).append('<span value=' + value.CityId + '>' + value.CityName + '</span>').appendTo(ul);
          };
```

this will handle all requirements for Autocomplete e.g. Press of downarrow,uparrow and enter for selection.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: It seems to be right - no erros!  but I dont see the returned result. do I need to append the data to some object?

Comment: no not required, as we are returning data in response(datas.d) in success method, this will automatically do it. If the object returned from server is in `[{CityId:1,CityName:'A'},{CityId:2,CityName:'B'}]` format then it shouldn't create any issue. If possible plz provide the array of data returned from server

Comment: Server side added. Thanks!

Comment: I can see the results with google develper, they just not display under the autocomplete textbox. maybe it's becuase I using it inside a modalpopup